# The lower bound of the number of cubic residue mod n.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For arbitrary positive integer $n$ ,

Denote $a\sim_n b \iff a^3\equiv b^3 \mod n$,

and $P(n):=\mathrm{Card}\{\mathbb{Z}/\sim_n\}$,

How to calculate the value $\displaystyle\inf_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}\frac{P(n)}{n}$?